Assembly language that I can input 2digit numbers and it will determine if it's even or odd
I have the code here, but it only displays 1 digit number. I don't know where I should edit so that I can input 2-digit numbers.
Here is the code:
.model small

.stack 100h



.data

    first_prompt db 'Enter first number: $'

    second_prompt db 10, 13, 'Enter second number: $'

    third_prompt db 10, 13, 'Enter third number: $'

    result_msg db 10, 13, 'The results are: $'

    even_msg db ' is even,$'

    odd_msg db ' is odd,$'

    newline db 0dh, 0ah, '$'



.code

main:

    mov ax, @data

    mov ds, ax



    ; Display prompts for the numbers

    mov ah, 9

    lea dx, first_prompt

    int 21h



    ; Read the first number

    mov ah, 1

    int 21h

    mov bl, al ; Store the first number



    ; Display prompts for the numbers

    mov ah, 9

    lea dx, second_prompt

    int 21h



    ; Read the second number

    mov ah, 1

    int 21h

    mov cl, al ; Store the second number



    ; Display prompts for the numbers

    mov ah, 9

    lea dx, third_prompt

    int 21h



    ; Read the third number

    mov ah, 1

    int 21h

    mov ch, al ; Store the third number



    ; Display result message

    mov ah, 9

    lea dx, result_msg

    int 21h



    ; Display the first number

    mov ah, 2

    mov dl, bl

    int 21h



    ; Display whether the first number is even or odd

    mov ah, 9

    mov al, bl

    test al, 1

    jz first_even

    lea dx, odd_msg

    int 21h

    jmp second_check

first_even:

    lea dx, even_msg

    int 21h



    ; Display the second number

second_check:

    mov ah, 2

    mov dl, cl

    int 21h



    ; Display whether the second number is even or odd

    mov ah, 9

    mov al, cl

    test al, 1

    jz second_even

    lea dx, odd_msg

    int 21h

    jmp third_check

second_even:

    lea dx, even_msg

    int 21h



    ; Display the third number

third_check:

    mov ah, 2

    mov dl, ch

    int 21h



    ; Display whether the third number is even or odd

    mov ah, 9

    mov al, ch

    test al, 1

    jz third_even

    lea dx, odd_msg

    int 21h

    jmp exit_program

third_even:

    lea dx, even_msg

    int 21h



exit_program:

    ; Display new line

    mov ah, 9

    lea dx, newline

    int 21h



    ; Exit the program

    mov ah, 4Ch

    int 21h



end main

I have already changed some of it, but the results are still wrong.

Have you read the docs for what doing int 21h with ah=1 does?  Also, have you considered using an asm library (perhaps Irvine32)?  They have written some of these common routines for you.
